# My Guessing Game

Tags: python, random, hangman

This is a project that I remade to help me understand function definitions better. It may not be great but I am proud of it.

I would love to have you review this project and tell me what I could improve in this project, as well as in general.

```
from all_wrd import words
import random
import re

class Game:
    def __init__(self, user_guess, secret_word):

        # the user_guess is the the letter that the user/player inputs first
        # the secret_word is the random word that has been choicen out of the imported all_wrd file

        self.user_guess = user_guess
        self.secret_word = secret_word

    def checker(self):

        # creates a list of dots that are the same lenght as the secret_word
        right_guess = ["."]*len(self.secret_word)

        # amount of wrong user guesses 
        wrong_guess = 0

        while True :
            if self.user_guess not in self.secret_word:
                print("wrong guess")

                wrong_guess += 1

                print(right_guess)
                user = input("guess a letter : ")

                if user in self.secret_word:
                    print('you got it right 1 ')
                    
                     # replaces 1 or more of the dots with the correct user_input and puts it in the correct position  
                    for m in re.finditer(user , self.secret_word):
                        right_guess[m.end()-1] = user

                    print(right_guess)
                
                    # checks to see if all the user/player guessed all the letters of the secret_word
                    if '.' not in right_guess:
                        print("you got all the letters!! ")

                        finish_game = input("finish the game by typing the entire word please : ")

                        # checks to see if user spells the enitere word correctly 
                        # if so he or she wins the game end the game ends 
                        if finish_game == self.secret_word:
                            print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT , YOU WIN !!!")
                            break

                        # else the user loses and the game ends 
                        else:
                            print("you lose\nwell played ")
                            break

                    if user not in self.secret_word:
                        print("you got it wrong ")
                        wrong_guess += 1

                        user = input("guess another letter : ")

                        # if the user guesses the word wrong 3 times the game ends and user loses
                        if wrong_guess == 3:
                            print("you are out of guesses ")
                            print(f"\nthe word was {self.secret_word}")
                            break

            # checks to see if the first input was in the secret_word 
            if self.user_guess in self.secret_word:
                print("right guess ")
       
                # replaces 1 or more of the dots with the correct user_input and puts it in the correct position
                for m in re.finditer(self.user_guess, self.secret_word):
                    right_guess[m.end() - 1] = self.user_guess
                print(right_guess)


                new_guess = input("guess a letter please : ")

                if new_guess in self.secret_word :
                    print("got it right")

                     # replaces 1 or more of the dots with the correct user_input and puts it in the correct position
                    for m in re.finditer(new_guess, self.secret_word):
                        right_guess[m.end() - 1] = new_guess
                    print(right_guess)

                    # checks to see if the user/player guessed all the letters correctly
                    if '.' not in right_guess:

                        print("you got all the letters!! ")
                        last = input("finish the game by typing the entire word please : ")

                        if last == self.secret_word:
                            print("GOOD JOB YOU GUESSED THE WORD , CONGRATULATIONS!!!")
                            break

                        else:
                            print("you guess the wrong letter :(\nyou losed")
                            break

                if new_guess not in self.secret_word:

                    print("you got it wrong")

                    wrong_guess+=1

                    print(right_guess)
                    new_guess = input("try again : ")

                    if wrong_guess == 3:
                        print("you are out of guesses")
                        print(f"\nthe word was {self.secret_word}")
                        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_word = random.choice(words)
    g = Game(input("guess a letter : "),the_word)
    g.checker()
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you'd benefit from moving duplicated logic into functions. Additionally, you manage all of your state within the `checker()` method, when this state could be stored on the `Game` object. Passing a user guess into the constructor seems really strange. There's nothing special about the first guess, so don't treat it as a special case.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, secret_word):

        # the user_guess is the the letter that the user/player inputs first
        # the secret_word is the random word that has been choicen out of the imported all_wrd file

        self.secret_word = secret_word

        self.wrong_guesses = 0
        self.guessed = set()

    def guess(self,letter):
        if letter in self.secret_word:
            print("you got it right")
            self.guessed.add(letter)
        else:
            print("wrong guess")
            self.wrong_guesses+=1

    # answer with dots for letters not guessed
    def partial_answer(self):
        return ''.join([
            letter if letter in self.guessed else '.'
            for letter in self.secret_word
        ])
    
    def have_won(self):
        return self.partial_answer()==self.secret_word

    def play(self):
        while self.wrong_guesses<3 and not self.have_won():
            self.guess(input("guess a letter : "))
            print(self.partial_answer())

        if self.have_won():
            print("YOU GOT IT RIGHT , YOU WIN !!!")
        else:
            print("you are out of guesses ")
            print(f"\nthe word was {self.secret_word}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game("dude")
    game.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Verbs for methods

```
g.checker()
```

should be

```
g.check()
```

"Checker" would be an appropriate name for a class or variable; "check" for a function.

### Grammar

`you losed` -> `you lost`